# Uint8List vs List<int> what is the difference?

Tags: dart, type-conversion, byte

In my flutter project I have some libraries that are using `Uint8List` (mostly cryptography stuff), and some libraries that are using `List<int>`(grpc).
I want to unify a bunch of functions that are working with bytes in best way possible.
Which cases are appropriate for Uint8List and List (which way is better to work with bytes in dart lang)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Uint8List` is a specialized type of `List<int>`.  As explained by [the `Uint8List` documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/Uint8List-class.html):

> For long lists, this implementation can be considerably more space- and time-efficient than the default `List` implementation.
>
> Integers stored in the list are truncated to their low eight bits, interpreted as an unsigned 8-bit integer with values in the range 0 to 255.

You should prefer using `Uint8List` for bytes.  There are a number of functions that take or return sequences of bytes as `List<int>`, but usually that's for historical reasons, and changing those APIs to use `Uint8List` now would break existing code. (There was an attempt to change the APIs, but it broke more code than expected and changes to some of the APIs had to be reverted.)

In cases where functions return a sequence of bytes as `List<int>`, usually the returned object is actually a `Uint8List`, so casting it often will work:

```dart
var list = foo() as Uint8List;
```

If you're unsure, you could write a helper function that performs the cast if possible but falls back to copying the `List<int>` into a new `Uint8List` object:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

/// Converts a `List<int>` to a [Uint8List].
///
/// Attempts to cast to a [Uint8List] first to avoid creating an unnecessary
/// copy.
extension AsUint8List on List<int> {
  Uint8List asUint8List() {
    final self = this; // Local variable to allow automatic type promotion.
    return (self is Uint8List) ? self : Uint8List.fromList(this);
  }
}
```

and use it as:

```dart
var list = foo().asUint8List();
```

(The `asUint8List()` extension also is available via my [`dartbag`](https://pub.dev/packages/dartbag) package.)