# Why doesn't File provide an interface to read the contents to return Uint8List data in dart?

Tags: dart

I want to read the contents of a file piece by piece through an interface (instead of reading the whole file at once with `readAsBytes()`). `openRead()` seems to do the trick, but it returns a `List<int>` type. And I expect it to be `Uint8List`, because I want to do block operations on some of the contents.

If you convert the returned `List<int>` to `Uint8List`, it seems to make a copy of the contents, which is a big loss in efficiency.

Is this how it was designed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically Dart used `List<int>` for sequences of bytes before a more specific `Uint8List` class was added.  A `Uint8List` is a subtype of `List<int>`, and in most cases where a Dart SDK function returns a `List<int>` for a list of bytes, it's actually a `Uint8List` object.  You therefore usually can just cast the result:

```dart
var file = File('/path/to/some/file');
var stream = file.openRead();
await for (var chunk in stream) {
  var bytes = chunk as Uint8List;
}
```

If you are uncomfortable relying on the cast, you can create [a helper function that falls back to creating a copy if and only if necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69091484/).

There have been efforts to change the Dart SDK function signatures to use `Uint8List` types explicitly, and that has happened in some cases (e.g. `File.readAsBytes`).  Such changes would be breaking API changes, so they cannot be done lightly.  I don't know why `File.openRead` was not changed, but it's quite likely that the amount of breakage was deemed to be not worth the effort. (At a minimum, the SDK documentation should be updated to indicate whether it is guaranteed to return a `Uint8List` object.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/39947)

Alternatively, instead of using `File.openRead`, you could use [`File.open`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/File/open.html) and then use [`RandomAccessFile.read`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/RandomAccessFile/read.html), which is declared to return a `Uint8List`.