# How to target specific int (bits) in an int array into Uint16 or 32?

Tags: flutter, dart, byte

I have a list of int like the following.

```
List<int> data = [52, 24, 40, 0, 198, 7, 98, 0, 0, 0, 40, 223, 30, 0, 203, 244, 0, 0]
```

I would like to generate 8/16/32 Uint so that I can process them. For example, bytes 2 & 3 is actually a 16 bit value, so both bytes need to be added, in the right order which in this case is `00000000 00101000` .

Question: How can I target specific index to add to a specific Uint type?

```
eg.. Uint16 powerValue = data[2] data[3];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Presuming that your `List<int>` is meant to be a list of bytes, convert your `List<int>` into a `Uint8List` with [`Uint8List.fromList`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/Uint8List.fromList.html).  Note that your [`List<int>` might already be a `Uint8List`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69091484/); if so, just cast it with `as Uint8List` to avoid an unnecessary copy.
2. Access the [`Uint8List.buffer` getter](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/TypedData/buffer.html) to obtain the underlying `ByteBuffer`.
3. You then can use methods such as [`ByteBuffer.asUint16List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer/asUint16List.html), [`ByteBuffer.asUint32List`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer/asUint32List.html), etc.  These methods allow you to specify a starting offset and length.
4. Alternatively, if you need more control (for example, if you want to interpret bytes using the non-native endianness), then you can use [`ByteBuffer.asByteData`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer/asByteData.html) to obtain a `ByteData` view that provides methods such as [`getUint16`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteData/getUint16.html), [`getUint32`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteData/getUint32.html), etc.

Putting it all together, for your specific example:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  List<int> data = [
    52,
    24,
    40,
    0,
    198,
    7,
    98,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    40,
    223,
    30,
    0,
    203,
    244,
    0,
    0
  ];
  var bytes = Uint8List.fromList(data);
  var powerValue = bytes.buffer.asByteData().getUint16(2, Endian.little);
  print(value); // Prints: 40
}
```

Of course, if this is just something you need to do as a one-off case, you also could just do bitwise operations yourself:

```dart
var powerValue = (data[3] << 8) | data[2];
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. Can you please explain the byte offset in the getUint16 function?

Comment: @Yonkee The byte offset is which byte to start reading from.  For example, to read a `Uint16` from `list[4]` and `list[5]`, you'd use `getUint16(4, ...)` (or alternatively `...asByteData(4).getUint16(0, ...)`).