# Flutter/Dart read portions of file as bytes rather than List<int>?

Tags: flutter, dart, io

Right now, I'm reading files with the openRead() stream because I wasn't wanting to read in the entire file at once with readAsBytesSync() since some files might be multiple gigabytes and could possibly have some memory exception when reading huge files. But when I read in a small portion of a file and process the bytes with other libraries, I am having to convert the List that openRead() provides to a Uint8List.fromList() before I can provide the read bytes to other functionality that wont' accept a List.

These constant conversions are probably taking up processing time which I'd rather not have to spend. Is it possible to read portions of a file the way openRead()'s stream does but also get a Uint8List rather than having to convert the list? Or is there a way to do a readAsBytesSync() but supply start/end offsets which this function doesn't have?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/openRead.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/readAsBytesSync.html (no start/end arguments)

Comment: Whenever I try to cast with 'Uint8List test = inputBuffer as Uint8List;', I always get the error `type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'Uint8List' in type cast` 

Is that normal?

Comment: Yes. It is declared as List<int> because it is collecting "chunks" from openRead's 'await for' loop. Those chunks come back as List<int> so that's why I declared inputBuffer as a List<int>.

Comment: `File.openRead` *should* be returning a `Stream<List<int>>` where each stream elements is actually a `Uint8List`.  It's declared to return a `Stream<List<int>>` instead of `Stream<Uint8List>` for historical reasons.  I don't know why you're getting a `TypeError` when casting since you haven't shown actual code, and I therefore don't know what `inputBuffer` is. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69091484/