# How to transform Stream<List<int>> to Stream<Uint8List> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, casting, stream, transform

I have a Flutter function from a package that returns a `Stream<List<int>>` and I want to cast/transform to a `Stream<Uint8List>`. I'm not very familiar with dart Streams so I will appreciate any help/suggestion on this topic.

I have tried to `cast()`, `as Stream<Uint8List>`, but did not work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very likely that you have a `Stream<List<int>>` [that already has `Uint8List` elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69091484/).  If so, you should be able to cast the *elements* (not the `Stream` itself) by using [`Stream.cast`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/cast.html):

```dart
var uint8ListStream = originalStream.cast<Uint8List>();
```

If that doesn't work, then you can create a new `Stream` from the original with [`Stream.map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/map.html), copying each `List<int>` into a new `Uint8List`:

```dart
var uint8ListStream = originalStream.map((list) => Uint8List.from(list));
```

You also could use `asUint8List` (from the answer I linked to above) to combine the approaches, copying into new `Uint8List`s only if necessary:

```dart
var uint8ListStream = originalStream.map((list) => list.asUint8List());
```

Comment: First suggestion got me this error: Unhandled Exception: type 'MergeStream<List<int>>' is not a subtype of type 'Stream<Uint8List>' in type cast, but second ones, creating a Stream from original with Stream.map worked fine!! thanks a lot for your help @jamesdlin!